# Amazon SES - Send email using IAM Roles

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, amazon-iam, amazon-ses

I am using the Amazon SES Java SDK and I want to send a mail from my EC2 server whilst taking advantage of IAM roles

I am wondering is this possible using just Java mail or do I need to use the SES SDK?

Can anyone point me at any examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send mails directly using SMTP credentials generated from Amazon SES account using Java Mail. However, if using API's to send emails, it is recommended to use the SDK.